# Drop columns of a dataframe using inverse index

Tags: r

The following function which takes in a dataframe and a list of column indexes as an argument, and prints them out.

```
testfunc1 <- function (df, cols){
  print(df[cols])
}
```

For example, the following function call prints out the 3rd and 4th columns of the dataframe

```
testfunc1(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[,1:4], -c(1,2))
```

However, I am also trying to keep the function parameters the same and figure out how to print the inverse of the column indexes.

For example I want the same function call as above, to also print out the 1st and 2nd column of the dataframe without adding a new parameter

I have multiplied the indexes by -1 to invert them, but is there a better approach to do this?

```
testfunc1 <- function (df, cols){
      print(df[cols])
      print(df[-1*cols])
}
```

*p.s. - I'm trying to use only base R to do this

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: Looks so simple that maybe there is no better approach. What are your intentions when creating that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind printing the resulted data frames in a `list`, you can try

```
testfunc2 <- function(df, col){ 
    list(df[col], df[-col])
}

testfunc2(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[, 1:4], -c(1, 2))
```

I found that for your example, `testfunc2` is in average more than ten times faster than `testfunc1`.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(testfunc1(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[,1:4], -c(1,2)), testfunc2(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[,1:4], -c(1,2)))

# Unit: microseconds
#                                                          expr    min     lq     mean median      uq
# testfunc1(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[, 1:4], -c(1, 2)) 2651.2 2895.7  5377.846 3839.6 6034.20
# testfunc2(subset(iris, Species == "setosa")[, 1:4], -c(1, 2))  106.3  137.4   306.929  206.2  282.65
#     max neval cld
# 19966.6   100   b
#  2859.5   100  a
```

In addition to shorter execution time, another advantage of storing the resulted data frames in a list is that it makes accessing different parts of the printed data frames easier.

In the previous example, `df[col]` can be accessed using `testfunc2(...)[[1]]`, while `df[-col]` using `testfunc2(...)[[2]]`.